# Хотелось бы сделать 3D логическую игру.. но как?

Tags: vb6, разработка-игр, 3d

Закончив очередную 2Д игру хочется перейти в трёхмерное пространство :)
Знаю хорошо язык программирования Visual Basic 6.0 
Хорошо моделирую 3Д объекты в Wings3D и CINEMA4D
Достаточно ли этого или что ещё надо чтобы создать простое приложение с любым созданным 3D объектом?

База игры строится на "почти" шахматной доске, только с размером 20х20 (а не 8х8) и по нему можно будет передвигать кубики, переворачивая их

Comment: Сначала нужно написать дизайн документ, чтобы можно было объяснить другим людям что из себя представляет игра.

Comment: Если с 3D математикой порядок, крепкие нервы, то можно смотреть в сторону physx 2. Он на C++. 

Это движок с настоящей физикой, а за физическими движками будущее.

Для него есть огромное количество примеров, в самой скачиваемой версии. Можно понять, как помещать в пространство объект, управлять камерой, а главное там уже прописана обработка столкновений для твёрдых тел и их деформация, разрыв тканей, разрушение мягких тел.

Comment: Но это очень сложный движок, чтобы въехать в 3D математику можно почитать замечательную книгу Конгера "Физика для разработчиков компьютерных игр"(+CD). Там самостоятельно напишите реализацию 2-3-4D vector и matrix, обработчик коллизий(столкновений). Реализуете столкновению шаров для боулинга в невесомости(очень впечатляет).

Comment: Осталось узнать, где это всё можно отыскать :) 
И тут на днях установил Visual Studio 2012 так она пустую програмку даже не хочет запускать.. (так же проверял готовые маленькие проекты от разных разработчиков) - не работает...  не понимаю в чём может быть проблема

Comment: Ну если честно, то настройка и компиляция physx довольно сложное дело. 
Visual Studio 2012 много чего не нравится(при включенной опции SDL). Замучился переводить код под неё. 

Если знаете только visual basic изучать будет сложновато.


Вот посмотрите может поможет.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lghrRCez_xA

Еще здесь статья:

http://gcup.ru/publ/programmirovanie_3d_grafiki_na_visual_basic_6_i_directx_8/1-1-0-239


Здесь могут быть исходники 3D на visual basic:

http://sources.codenet.ru/index.php?cid=10&o=0&start=20

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно найти подходящий(под Ваши требования и, очень желательно, с обёрткой для VB) графический движок, определиться с форматом моделей(их ведь нужно не только смоделлить, но и сохранить в определенном формате. Нередко, с ограничениями, по сравнению с исходной моделью.). Изучить API графического движка и вперед =)

Для начала стоит брать что-нибудь несложное и ненавороченное. Позволяющее просто рисовать модельки, без сценеграфа и шейдеров(или с набором стандартных шейдеров вроде параллакс маппинга). К сожалению, не знаю, что актуально сейчас в VB.

Игровую логику, уверен, осилите. :)